# ASP.NET MVC 5 adding singleton instance to application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to add singleton object to MVC application (for learning purposes). I'd prefer to instantiate singleton object somewhere in `Application_Start()` method and then for example access it in controller. I don't want to use other libraries, like [unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671.aspx). Is there any way to do so?

Comment: What does the singleton pattern have *anything* to do with asp.net-mvc?

Comment: The point of using singleton is you don't need to instantiate it outside of its own class..

Comment: @FCin, not necessarily. There are situations where the instantiation may happen later or outside the class itself. The pattern specifies only that there's just one instance, not how or where it is created.

Comment: This is arguably not a duplicate in that the OP is requesting the instantiation to happen outside the class itself, in the `Application_Start`. This is not addressed in the linked post as a duplicate.